# Docker container not mounting data volume

Tags: docker, docker-container

I've got a locally maintained Docker image that, for some reason, is not mounting the local data volume in the container.

```
docker run -d -v /mnt/melissadata:/usr/local/tomcat/appconf -p 7070:7070 -p 80:8080 --restart on-failure:3 --name addrgeo imagename
```

On my local data volume, I have a number of files the service needs, but it's unable to find them.

I know the volume is mounted.

```
$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN    RM    SIZE    RO    TYPE    MOUNTPOINT
xvdi    202:128    0     10G     0     disk    /mnt/melissadata
```

And it appears that the Docker container can see the volume...

```
$ docker inspect
...
"Mounts": [
  {
    "Source": "/mnt/melissadata",
    "Destination": "/usr/local/tomcat/appconf",
    "Mode": "",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": "rprivate"
  }
],
```

`findmnt` returns:

```
$ sudo findmnt -o TARGET,PROPAGATION /mnt/melissadata
TARGET           PROPAGATION
/mnt/melissadata private
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you run `docker exec` to enter the container and navigate the tree?  The volume appears to be mounted.

Comment: I did. There is nothing in the directory where it should be mounted.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo findmnt -o TARGET,PROPAGATION /mnt/melissadata` ?

Comment: @RicardoBranco I updated the question with the answer to this.

Comment: Does anonymous user have read permission to the files?

Comment: I actually just figured it out. The data on the mounted volume expires every ~2 months. When it was last updated, the ownership was changed from `root:root` to `1000:1000` - probably from the way it was extracted. Once I updated the ownership and restarted the docker, everything worked perfectly.

Comment: Scratch that. It worked once. After restarting the docker, it's failing again. Nothing has changed since the last successful run. Yes, public users have access to all of the files and directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this was happening is because the Docker daemon uses devicemapper to devicemapper to back Docker's layer storage. If the volume was mounted after the Docker daemon was started, then Docker doesn't know it exists. A restart of the Docker daemon fixes it.

`sudo service docker restart`